# Base64 Invalid String error

Tags: c#, php, encryption, base64

I have a problem working with Base64 Strings in C#

I have an .exe which is called from php. It gets 2 params and returns an encrypted key.
(The .exe is where I have the problem)

In php I do this:

```
<?php
$key = "AAAA";
$pass=" AAAA";
echo shell_exec("cryptograph.exe generateKey $key $pass");
?>
```

It should work, becouse those are base 64 strings, or at least, I understand that a String with a length multiple of 4 is a valid base 64 string.

But I get the following(Is in spanish but I will translate it bellow):

```
Encrypt en System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) 
en cryptograph.Cryptography.Encrypt(String plainStr, String completeEncodedKey, Int32 keySize) en cryptograph.Cryptography.generateKey(String key, String pass) 
en cryptograph.cryptograph.Main(String[] args) 
La entrada no es una cadena Base 64 v lida porque contiene un car cter que no es Base 64, m s de dos caracteres de relleno o un car cter de relleno que no es un espacio en blanco
```

Basically it sais that it is no valid Base64 String, becouse it contains a char which is no Base 65, more than too filler(relleno is translate like that?) chars which are no whitespaces.

This is part of the c# code.

```
    public static void generateKey(String key, String pass)
    {
        String e = Encrypt(pass, key, 256);
        Console.WriteLine("Entro generateKey");
        System.Console.WriteLine(e);
    }

    private static string Encrypt(string plainStr, string completeEncodedKey, int keySize)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Entro Encrypt");
        RijndaelManaged aesEncryption = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesEncryption.KeySize = keySize;
        aesEncryption.BlockSize = 128;
        aesEncryption.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        aesEncryption.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        Console.WriteLine(completeEncodedKey);
        aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
        aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[1]);
        byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainStr);
        ICryptoTransform crypto = aesEncryption.CreateEncryptor();
        Console.WriteLine("Abajo de crypto");
        // The result of the encryption and decryption            
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
```

The problem, happens in some of these two lines:

```
aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[1]);
```

Comment: have you tried a comma between the arguments and not a space? that's what the code looks like it expects

Comment: When you Console.WriteLine of completeEncodedKey, what exactly is written?

Comment: Just tried and same result. cryptograph.exe is a command line program. You can open cmd and use it, when you pass params you separate them with a space.

Comment: "I understand that a String with a length multiple of 4 is a valid base 64 string." --> This is really wrong. This is one of that cases where Wikipedia ha to be pointed out: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, it's really not clear what `completeEncodedKey` is meant to really represent. If it's the result of cryptograph.exe which is meant to return an *encrypted* key, then surely you need to *decrypt* it - which isn't what you're actually doing here.

Anyway, I'm sure this is the problem (twice, once for IV and once for the key):

```
aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString
    (Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey)).Split(',')[0]);
```

Let's split this up a bit for sanity:

```
byte[] completeBinaryKey = Convert.FromBase64String(completeEncodedKey);
string asciiKey = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(completeBinaryKey);
string[] parts = asciiKey.Split(',');
string ivBase64 = parts[0];
aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ivBase64);
```

For a start, `ASCIIEncoding.UTF8` is extremely confusing. Why bring ASCII into it if you really just want UTF-8? You should use `Encoding.UTF8` to be clearer. However, I don't think you *actually* want this at all.

Why are you converting from base64 *twice*? If "overall" value is UTF-8-encoded text, why is it converted to base64?

I strongly suspect your text is *actually* of the form:

```
<base64-encoded-iv>,<base64-encoded-key>
```

In that case, you just need to split *then* to the base64-conversion:

```
string[] parts = completeEncodedKey.Split(',');
aesEncryption.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(parts[0]);
aesEncryption.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(parts[1]);
```

Comment: Ok I will try,
Sorry if it is confusing :( the code is not mine, It was given to me to make it work from php.
Thanks

Comment: The error changed now:
“Specified initialization vector (IV) does not match the block size for this algorithm” 
Does this means that it has to be 16 bytes long?

Comment: @leojg: Probably. To be honest it's *very* unclear what the data you've actually got in `completeEncodedKey` is meant to be.