# Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string. AES in C#

Tags: c#, cryptography, base64, aes

Im getting the error 'Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.' on this line

```
rm.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(text)).Split(',')[0]);
```

Here is the code:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String s = generateKey(256);
        textBox2.Text = s;
    }

    private String generateKey(int keySize)
    {
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        rm.KeySize = keySize;
        rm.BlockSize = 128;
        rm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rm.GenerateIV();
        String iv = Convert.ToBase64String(rm.IV);
        rm.GenerateKey();
        String key = Convert.ToBase64String(rm.Key);
        string completeKey = iv + "," + key;

        return Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(completeKey));
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == "" || textBox2.Text == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please generate a key!");
        }
        else
        {
            String key = textBox2.Text;
            String strToBeEncoded = textBox1.Text;
            String s = encryptAES(strToBeEncoded, key, 256);
            outputBox.Text = s;
        }
    }

    private String encryptAES(String text, String key, int keySize)
    {
        RijndaelManaged rm = new RijndaelManaged();
        rm.KeySize = keySize;
        rm.BlockSize = 128;
        rm.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
        rm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
        rm.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(text)).Split(',')[0]);
        rm.Key = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[1]);
        byte[] plainText = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);
        ICryptoTransform crypto = rm.CreateEncryptor();
        byte[] cipherText = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherText);
    }
}
```

Comment: you may want to look at this, I think this is a dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15419542/base64-invalid-string-error

Comment: Perhaps you should split that expression up into multiple lines and determine exactly where the problem is. Which call to `Convert.FromBase64String` is failing?

Comment: Darn now I have got new kids on the block in my head. Your fault.

Comment: IVs are generally not kept with the key but with the ciphertext, while not the question,  iv with same key is not supposed to be reused ever. FYI

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to pull the IV out of the string you will be encrypting.

Try changing:

```
rm.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(text)).Split(',')[0]);
```

to:

```
rm.IV = Convert.FromBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(key)).Split(',')[0]);
```

Comment: Also, don't forget to properly dispose of the `RijndaelManaged` and `ICryptoTransform` objects. Even better if they were wrapped in some `Using` statements.